How to fetch all records from DynamoDB using DataGrip?
I have connected the DynamoDB using DataGrip, and when I select a table, it only returns 147 rows of that table, but we have more than 20k records in that table.
Database logs here
Just wondering how can I fetch all records in DataGrip.

We have a similar issue reported on our tracker:
https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/DBE-19642/DynamoDB-cant-retrieve-all-rows-when-it-needs-to-paginate
Please ensure you have the 0.7 jdbc driver version installed. If it doesn't work, please report your issue here
https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/newIssue?project=DBE
